# How to keep object tag when parsing HTML Content use SimpleHTMLDom

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I want to keep all content  from div with class content(keep all original html format include object flash video). But when i use SimpleHTMLDom to parsing i don't get all content that i want .

```
//File test.html
<div class="content">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
          <object id="fpt_player_3548_0" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" height="296" width="470"><param value="http://st.f2.vnecdn.net/f/v37/fptplayer_embed.swf" name="movie"><param value="high" name="quality"><param value="transparent" name="wmode"><param value="xmlPath=http://vnexpress.net/video/vne-info/id/3548/type/2&amp;colorAux=0x0099ff&amp;colorBorder=0x333333&amp;colorMain=0xffffff&amp;local=embed&amp;mAuto=false&amp;autoHide=false&amp;trackurl=&amp;tracktype=video" name="flashvars"><param value="true" name="allowfullscreen"><param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess"><embed id="fpt_player_3548_0" name="fpt_player_3548_0" src="http://st.f2.vnecdn.net/f/v37/fptplayer_embed.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="xmlPath=http://vnexpress.net/video/vne-info/id/3548/type/2&amp;colorAux=0x0099ff&amp;colorBorder=0x333333&amp;colorMain=0xffffff&amp;local=embed&amp;mAuto=false&amp;autoHide=false&amp;trackurl=&amp;tracktype=video" height="296" width="470">
          </object>
        </div>
        <p class="Normal">
        <em>Something</em> 
        More contents
        </p>
</div>
```

Code to parsing HTML using SimpleHTMLDom

```
$html = file_get_html('test.html');
// find all div tags with class=content
foreach($html->find('div.content') as $e)
echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

This output i have (object tag hidden)

```
<div style="text-align:center;">    
  <div id="video-3548" data-component="true" data-component-type="video" data-component-value="3548" data-component-typevideo="2" style="display:none;">
  </div>
</div>
<p class="Normal">
  <em>Something</em> 
  More contents
</p>
```

Comment: Make sure the object element really is in the page source you loaded. The object element might get inserted via Javascript after the page loaded in your browser. You cannot scrape it via PHP then because PHP will not evaluate any JavaScript. Consider using a *headless browser*, like phantom.js.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use phantom.js

Comment: They have ample documentation: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki

Comment: It works, I just tried it ! ... The output example you gave above isnt for the input example you gave at the begining. There's a `<div id="video-3548" ...`  instead of the `object` tag...

Comment: @Enissay yeah but i want it same with the input gave at the beginning . I have tried .